# I can't create view

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

I need to create but I obtain a syntax error in this line

```
CREATE
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER = "root" @"%" SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW "name_schema"."table" AS select....
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `"root" @"%"` should have no space in it. The view name should not be encapsulated in double quotes (that's treating it as a string) `VIEW name_schema.view_name` or you can use backticks as your encapsulating character if it's required. If that doesn't solve it, please share the actual error as it probably contains a clue.

Comment: I modify with your suggest but I obtnain the same error: Errore SQL [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER = "root"@"%" SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW' at line 2

Comment: in which environment do you run this script?

Comment: I mean IDE, because It works well in phpmyqdmin

Comment: try : CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER = "root"@"%" SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW name_schema.ViewName AS select....

Comment: @FatemehNB the error persist!

Comment: Maybe you can rephrase like this "CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@"%" SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `name_schema`.`table` AS select...."

Comment: `` use bactiks but i don't get it.. the first is name view right? why don't just put simple like `create view lala as select....` ?